# Is there a way to correct for degrees of freedom when using a generalized linear model with a Poisson distribution featuring random effects?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model, poisson-regression, degrees-of-freedom, approximation

I am running a generalized linear mixed effect model with a Poisson distribution to analyse count data. The model has a random effect that takes into account multiple observation obtained by the same participant.

Do you know if there is any way to calculate the Wald test for the slope being different from zero but at the same correcting for the degree of freedom. I am looking at something similar to the Satterthwaite approximation available for linear mixed effect models.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. My understanding is:

- when the distribution linked to your test-statistics (e.g. z-value, t-value, chi-square, incidence rate ratios) depends on the number of degrees of freedom, then your p-value will not only depend on the type of distribution (e.g. Gaussian, Student's t, Poisson,...) and the test-statistics, but (of course) also on the number of degrees of freedom.
- examples of distributions that depend on the number of degrees of freedom: Chi-Square distribution, Student's t distribution (here you should report test-statistics, degrees of freedom and p-values)
- examples of distributions that do not depend on the number of degrees of freedom: Gaussian distribution, **Poisson distribution** (here you should just report test-statistics and p-values).